# "My Logins for <insert username here>" sounds.. well, awkward

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, login

That's about [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current).

I realize the name is in the title for mods, who can see others' logins, but that just doesn't sound right. If it is my own "My Logins" page, then the name can be removed. If it is seen by some mod, the title and "My Logins" header can have "My" removed.

> [image]

Comment: It's showing the name when you view your own profile as well,  don't see any reason to change it only for this specific screen. I agree the wording can be changed to make it consistent though - "User [name here] - Logins".

Comment: @Sha wait, that's *my* profile... And I guess that's how it looks to mods.

Comment: @Sha Or, I really don't get it, how would you consider "my logins for someone" to be a good title? Either my, or for someone. No need to state both.

Comment: It's informative. I want to know what I'm viewing - that's what the title is for. I really have no idea why you don't get it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, I agree that's weird. However, I don't think your solution makes it that much clearer.

My vote would be for something like `Login Credentials for <username>` for both your own and other people's profiles. That would both maintain consistency with other pages and avoid introducing a difference between page title for your own profile vs someone else's, all while not reading like it's in broken English at the same time.

Comment: And you'll implement it?

Comment: You don't even need "Credentials" - just `Logins for <user>` sounds fine.

Comment: @Tim Absolutely agree; but seems that Anna has already made a choice.

Comment: So, is it going to be implemented or not :)

Comment: @nicael I never said I would do it. You assumed. ;) Busy with other things right now, so all I did was propose a wording. Someone will get to it eventually... probably. Same as every other request.

Answer (score 6):

The "My Logins" part will tell the person viewing your account what section they are in your account. Since they are in the "My Logins" section for your account, the bar says "My Logins". And to know *whose* account they are viewing, which is you/nicael, it adds in "for nicael".

Sure it might be confusing for ***you*** but maybe not so much (or at all) for those viewing your account. If only mods can see it, why bother changing it anyways? The mods know what "My Logins for User's Name" means so it doesn't really make a good impact that can help the entire community. Normal users like me can't see that so really it doesn't matter to us non-mods.

EDIT: Okay, Patrick Hofman is right about the weirdness. It sounds weird. But it "nicael's My Logins" sounds even weirder and I can't really think up of something that still contains the "My Logins" part and the user's name. Anyways, if the mods agree to remove the "My", then the name should become, "nicael's Logins" or whoever's account the mod is visting.

Comment: I suppose that part was a little more for humor than answering the question.

Comment: You seem to make a valid point, though it just sounds strange. I'd remove "my".

Answer (score 5):

Think of "My Logins" as a whole, and that's what it is, as simple as that. It is the name of that section. Look at it as:

```
 (My Logins) for nicael
```

In case you insist this is illogical, a simple solution would be changing the whole section to just "Logins", it will do the job just fine and make things a bit clearer, but "My Logins" is also fine, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

It's technically correct, in that the "*My Logins*" as a reference name for a section of the site, and the "*for nicael*" as who's section of the site it is for.

But it doesn't sound right when you look at your own page because we automatically take the "My" as a self reference (as we are looking at our own login page), and there are *two* self references - "My" and "nicael".

It's like saying "this is my me page" - technically correct but sounds bad.

---

It could be worded better.
Removing the "My" seems most logical: *Logins for nicael*.
This is then fine for whoever visits it.

Ideally, it would determine who is visiting and change accordingly, boolean would do.
If owner then "My Logins", else "Logins for nicael".

And this is in keeping with other parts of the site, such as your own profile states "(Your about me is currently blank.)" whereas someone else's is "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.".

But, the "My Logins" is a site identifier, so we'd lose that, and it might be necessary - embedded in code/DB etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are right it sounds a little weird.

I think this has to do with consistency. If you look at the other options in the pane at the left, the `My` in `My Logins` really makes clear what you can expect clicking that.

When clicking on one of the other options, you will see the title is always put in a specific wording, for example `Flair for ...`. This is correct and makes sense.

The problem is though that in the case of `My Logins` there isn't an easy way to fit that title format in. You have to deviate from the title format it change the clear button label. I agree it could be changed, but I also like consistency...